# QGIS2Web - how to include additional mapping functions

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis2web

It is my understanding that the QGIS2Web generates a web map from my QGIS project by taking aspects of layers, styles and extent.

What would it take to include map functionality to the web map such as: buffer (radius search), simple attribute data filtering/querying, etc. to the web map?

I'm assuming I would need to add JavaScripts to make this work, but I'm not understanding how or where to add these JavaScripts within HTML to make these functions work with my published QGIS web map.

If it helps, I'm using WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First research how to achieve what you need in either Leaflet or Openlayers 3 using javascript. Then make your map using qgis2web. Export it, and then open your exported `index.html` in a text editor. You can either add the JS you've learned about into that index file, or put it in its own .js file and import that into `index.html` with a `<script>` tag.